# Set Array in Prepared stament db2 not working Java

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I'm facing this error fo
quiet a time now, I have this query:

```
String sql = "select US_KEY, US_LOGID, US_PASSWORD, US_SESSION, US_LASTLOGIN,\n" +
"   US_LASTACCESS, US_INTENTOS, US_NOMBRE, US_APELLIDO, US_ESTADO,\n" +
"   US_RAZON, US_RUT, US_DIGITOV, US_DIRECCION, US_EMAIL,\n" +
"   US_TELEFONO, US_CARGO, TU_KEY, EM_KEY, US_ULTIMO_CAMBIO_PASS,\n" +
"   US_TELEFONO2, US_PIN, US_BLOQUEO, US_CHECK_VOLATIL_PASS,\n" +
"   US_PV_KEY_SELECTED, US_VD_KEY_SELECTED, US_SC_KEY_SELECTED,\n" +
"   US_SECRET_ASK\n" +
" from DBUSER.USUARIO\n" +
" where US_KEY in (?) ";
```

and I'm settings the values like this:

```
Array array = query.getStatement().getConnection().createArrayOf("BIGINT",arrayOfLong);
query.setArray(param.getName(), array);
```

I'm connection to db2 database using com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver driver and getting this error:

> com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException:
>   [jcc][1091][10417][3.62.56] Invalid data conversion: Parameter
>   instance com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.p@6b09bb57 is invalid for the requested
>   conversion. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
>           at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:676)

It's not possible to set an array to a prepared stament to db2? It is not supported? Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the [site of IBM](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_rjvjdapi.html) seems that no, is not supported.

Search for method `setArray` in the table 19 (Support for `java.sql.PreparedStatement` methods).

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to programmatically create a loop to create the `IN (?,?,? ... )` clause, and another loop to do `setXXX()` for each `?` of the `PreparedStatement`.

Additonally, if your `IN` clause numbers in the 1000s elements you may have to split it and merge the partial results with `UNION`.

```
// construct IN clause
for (int i =0; i < us_keys.length(); i++ ) {
  inbuffer.append((i>0)?(',?'):('?'));
}
sql.append( "IN (" );
sql.append( inbuffer );
sql.append( ")" );
```

then

```
// assign all keys
int inkey=0;
for ( String us_key : us_keys ) {
   stmt.setString(++inkey,us_key);
}
```